# Calculate circumference values

Tags: php, geometry

I have a rectangular map, stored as multidimensional array (ie `$map[row][col]`) and I have to track down which squares are seen by a player, placed anywhere on this map.

Player visibility is circular with unknown radius (but given at run-time) and I only need integer solutions.

I know that circumference formula is

```
x^2 + y^2 <= r^2
```

but how can I store everything?
I need these values since then I can "reveal" map squares.

---

The best would be a multidimesional array (ie `__$sol[x][y]__`).
This is a piece of code that I'm using. It's not corrected since it assumes that vision is a square and not a circle.

*Calculating the square*

```
$this->vision_offsets_2 = array();
//visibility given as r^2
$mx = (int)(sqrt($this->viewradius2));

$mxArr = range($mx * -1, $mx + 1);
foreach ($mxArr as $d_row)
{
    foreach ($mxArr as $d_col)
    {
         $this->vision_offsets_2[] = array($d_row, $d_col);
    }
}
```

*This is how I apply that*

```
    foreach($player as $bot)
    {
        foreach($visibility as $offset)
        {
            $vision_row = $offset[0] + $bot[0];
            $vision_col = $offset[1] + $bot[1];

            if(isset($map[$vision_row][$vision_col]))
            {
                if( $map[$vision_row][$vision_col] == UNSEEN) {
                    $map[$vision_row][$vision_col] =  LAND; }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Here you can find the bot view: as you can see is a non perfect circle.
How can I track it? By the way, in this example radius^2 is 55, the orange circle is the player, brown squares are visible ones.

[image: bot view]

Comment: Explain what you're asking when you say, "How can I store everything?" There are lots of ways to store information for this problem and they all serve different goals. Two examples: a) Each object has an array of tiles it can see. b) One master list maintains all visible tiles.

Comment: my case is the second one. i have a big array where everything is stored. if i can see a square, i have the terrain value, otherwhise it's UNSEEN

Comment: Could you either update your question with a clarification based on the answers given, or accept one if it has helped for future Googlers?

Comment: @Whetstone i just added an example

Comment: Looking at your example, it seems like the problem is your resolution. If you want that to visually appear more like a circle you can either increase the apparent density of the map until it's not visually apparent that things are pixel-based or you can abandon the tiling idea and display your results by masking the resulting image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Structure

You're already referencing terrain in a grid. Store terrain objects in those grid values. Apply attributes to those objects. Check with something like

```
$map[$x][$y]->isVisible($player);
```

You'll need some methods in there for setting vision and tests for checking the user that is passed against a list of users who can see it. While you're at it, setup other related methods in those objects (I see references to land... `isLand()` and `isWater()` perhaps?).

You can even have vision cascade within objects such that you only need to move the position of a user and the object takes care of triggering off all the code to set nearby plots of land to visible.

### Math

We are given circumference.

```
double diameter = circumference / 3.14159
double radius = diameter / 2 //Normally done in one step / variable
```

Now we must know the distance between two points to compare it. Let's use map[4][7] and map[3][9].

```
int x0 = 4;
int y0 = 7;
int x1 = 3;
int y1 = 9;

double distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(x0 - x1, 2) + 
        Math.pow(y0 - y1, 2)
        );

System.out.println(distance); //2.23606797749979
```

Test `distance > radius`.

### Testing each square

- Put the above in a method: `visibleFrom(Square target)`

  - `radius` should be a globally accessible static variable when comparing.
  - Your `Square` object should be able to hand over its coordinates.

    - `target.getX()`
    - `target.getY()`
- Some optimizations can be had

  - Only checking things for circular distance when they're in the square.
  - Not checking anything for circular distance when purely along the `x` or `y` axis.
  - Figuring out the largest square that fits inside the circle and not checking boxes in that range for circular distance.
- Remember that premature optimization and over optimization are pitfalls.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i think i'll use it, but i still have the same issue: how can i decide whether a square is visible or not? i have to calculate the visible area around the player, in a circle way

Comment: I don't know why I misread the tags, but I did write Java code for your PHP question. Oops :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, but here's some things that should help you along.  As a warning these are untested, but the logic is sound.

```
 //You mentioned circumference, this will find out the circumference but I don't 
 //think you actually need it.
 $circumference_length = 2 * $visibility_range * 3.1415;

 //Plug in the player and target coordinates and how far you can see, this will
 //tell you if the player can see it.  This can be optimized using your object 
 //and player Objects.
 function canSee($player_x, $player_y, $vision_length, $target_x, $target_y){
      $difference_x = $target_x - $player_x;
      $difference_y = $target_y - $player_y;
      $distance = sqrt((pow($difference_x,2) + pow($difference_y, 2));

      if($vision < $distance){
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      } 

 }
```

Edit: In response to your clarification, you can use the above function to figure out if you should show the terrain objects or not.

```
foreach($player as $bot)
{
    foreach($terrain_thing as $terrain)
    {
        //ASSUMING THAT [0] IS ALWAYS X AND [1] IS ALWAYS y, set a third variable
        //to indicate visibility
        $terrain["is_visible"] = canSee($bot[0], $bot[1], $visibility_range, $terrain[0], $terrain[1])


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function like this would tell you if a map square is visible (using the distance of the centers of the squares as a metric; if you want to define visibility in another manner, which you probably would, things get much more complicated):

```
function is_visible($mapX, $mapX, $playerX, $playerY, $r) {
    return sqrt(pow($mapX - $playerX, 2) + pow($mapY - $playerY, 2)) <= $r;
}
```

You probably don't really need to store these values since you can easily calculate them on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Bresenham's circle drawing algorithm is what you're looking for.